# how to run multiple .sbatch scripts sequentially

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, sbatch

I have to run multiple sbatch slurm scripts for cluster. Say, I have 50 sbatch files and I am running them sequentially in terminal (am using Ubundu) as follows:

```
sbatch file1.sbatch  
sbatch file2.sbatch
.  
.  
.  
sbatch file50.sbatch
```

I want to simplify this 50 different commands to run in single command. As I am new working with terminal as well as cluster, I really don't know how to approach this problem. Kindly, suggest me some solution to perform this action (I guess that I need to use some for loop statements, but of which syntax is my doubt). I am completely confused, some relevant documents might also be helpful.

Thank you.

Update:
I tried the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash  
for i in {1..3}  
do   
    sbatch layer$i.sbatch  
done
```

But, it didn't create as separate jobs. Only single job is submitted as whole. So, this didn't worked for me.

```
$ ~/Marabou% sbatch call_sbatch.sbatch  
Submitted batch job 4576049
```

Thanks.

Update:
Following script works:

`import os`
  `os.system ("sbatch filename1.sbatch")`
 `os.system ("sbatch filename2.sbatch")`

Comment: Take a look at `for` loops in `bash`, they should solve you your problem: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-7.html

Comment: I tried this code as follows for just three files..

#!/bin/bash 
for i in {1..3} 
do 
sbatch layer$i.sbatch 
done 

But, it didn't create as separate jobs I guess..Only single job is submitted as whole. So, this dint work for me. 

$ ~/Marabou% sbatch call_sbatch.sbatch  
Submitted batch job 4576049 

Thanks.

Comment: Update the question with the new information. Code in comments is not readable. But I think you got the right code. Just lacking some semicolons.

Comment: I updated the code which I tried, but does not work...

Comment: Goood! Did you checked the format?

Comment: This sounds like a job for #SBATCH --array, provided each individual job is not dependent on the previous and there is some common iterator within each file

Answer (score 1):

The code you prepared should be run in the interactive shell, not launched to queues.

Just run your code directly:

```
$ sh call_sbatch.sbatch
```

or, if your file is executable,

```
$ ./call_sbatch.sbatch
```

It should run the inside lines with the loop you created and that loop will send to the queues the jobs you are interested in (in your sample code, three jobs: layer1.sbatch, layer2.sbatch and layer3.sbatch).